# using variable to define json object name

Tags: jquery, json, variables

I'm having a problem that I think is very easy to solve, but I can't seem to find an answer for it in my searches.

I have a bunch of json objects that I'm using.  Right now I get at the info like so for example:

```
for(image in data.everfi_commons.images) {
    alert(data.everfi_commons.images[image]);
}
```

what I'd like to do instead is instead of having the name 'everfi_commons' I'd like to just use a javascript variable that I've set up like so:

```
current_project = $(this).attr("id");  // this value is 'everfi_commons'
```

and then I thought you could just do data.current_project.images[image]

but this doesn't seem to work and I don't really understand why, any insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - just refer to the key as you refer to `image`:

```
for (image in data[current_project].images) {
    /*             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                   This will refer to a key with the name of 
                   whatever is in the current_project variable */
    alert(data[current_project].images[image]);
}
```

Comment: it's interesting, when I do this, it goes through the alerts listing the images one at a time...but it does it twice, so goes all the way through, one, two, three, four, and then does it again, one, two, three, four

Comment: @loriensleafs Can you post your `data` object?

Answer (score 2):

Try

`current_project = $(this).attr("id");  // this value is 'everfi_commons'`

then

`data[current_project].images[image]`

You can access object properties using `[]` in JavaScript, which is very handy.

Comment: Basically (just to give a small extra explanation for @loriensleaf): `x.abc` is the same as writing `x['abc']` in javascript. Meaning that if you have a variable containing the string `abc` (named `name`), `x[name]` would be another way to write the same.

Comment: thanks, that's super helpful to know.  Just out of curiosity, can you not write this in dot notation with the variable?

Comment: Well, to be honest, yes you can. I suggested the [] approach as a sanity check, to make sure the property does exist. But hey, at least I've shown something new :)